# Python Scrapy intermittently running pipeline

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

My pipeline `process_item` writes to two different csv files while also making an external soap request.

Sometimes these files are written to, most times not. When I run the crawl command I run `scrapy crawl parts` or `scrapy crawl parts -o results.json`. When I ouput to `results.json` there will always be results.

It seems to be very random. Sometimes the pipeline will create the files sometimes it will just append to the files that were already there.

Here's my pipeline:

Some information has been omitted

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
import csv
import zeep
from XXX import settings

class XXXPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        data = make_request(item)
        if (data):
            mainCsv = csv.writer(open(settings.csv_file_path, 'a+'), delimiter=',')
            imgPath = '/' + item['images'][0]['path']

            mainCsv.writerow([
                item['partNumber'], # sku,
                'simple', # _type
                'base', # _product_websites
                'Default', # _attribute_set
                4, # visiblity
                1, # status
                1, # is_in_stock
                10, # qty
                2, # tax_class_id
                1, # weight
                item['partNumber'] + data.PartDescription, # name
                9999, # price
                item['partNumber'] + ' ' + data.PartDescription, # description
                item['partNumber'] + ' ' + data.PartDescription, # short_description
                item['make'], # manufacturer_code
                imgPath, # image
                imgPath, # small_image
                imgPath, # thumbnail
                '"2,3"', # category_ids // Change based on site's categories
            ])

            imgCsv = csv.writer(open(settings.img_csv_file_path, 'a+'), delimiter=',')

            iterimg = iter(item['images'])
            next(iterimg)
            for img in iterimg:
                imgCsv.writerow([
                    item['partNumber'],
                    '/' + img['path']
                ])

        return item

def make_request(item):
    wsdl = 'XXX'
    client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)
    try:
        data = client.service.ExactPartLookup(
            userName='XXX',
            password='XXX',
            make=item['make'],
            partNumber=item['partNumber']
        )

        return data.PartInformation_v2[0]
    except:
        pass
```

The crawler:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import html
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse


class PartsSpiderPySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "parts"
    allowed_domains = ["XXX"]
    start_urls = ['https://XXX/']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = {'UserName': 'XXX', 'Password': 'XXX'}
        return scrapy.http.FormRequest(
            url='https://XXX/UserLogin/DoLogin',
            callback=self.after_login,
            formdata=data
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        for i in range(1, 34):
            request = scrapy.Request(
                url='https://XXX/Landing/AppendMoreParts?type=1&page=' + str(i),
                callback=self.get_parts,
            )
            yield request

    def get_parts(self, response):
        res = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.unescape(res['HTMLForGeneral']), 'html.parser')

        for part in soup.findAll('li'):
            item = {
                'partNumber': part.h5.a.string,
                'make': part.findAll('span')[0].string
            }
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url='https://XXX/Product/ProductImageListPartial?part=' + str(item['partNumber']) + '&make=' + str(item['make']),
                callback=self.get_img_urls,
                meta={'item': item},
            )

    def get_cross_info(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['crossReference'] = response.css('span span::text').extract()

        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://XXX/Product/GetPartModelPaging?make=' + str(item['make']) + '&partNumber=' + str(item['partNumber']),
            callback=self.get_related_models,
            meta={'item': item},
        )

    def get_related_models(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        res = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        if res['Result']:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html.unescape(res['Message']), 'html.parser')
            models = []
            for model in soup.findAll('a'):
                models.append(model.string)

            item['models'] = models
            return item

    def get_img_urls(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'html.parser')
        imgs = []
        for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'tumbimagepart'}):
            url = div.img['src']
            o = urlparse(url)
            imgs.append(o.scheme + "://" + o.netloc + o.path + '?width=750&mode=crop')

        item['image_urls'] = imgs

        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://XXX/Product/CrossReferencePartInfo?make=' + str(item['make']) + '&partNumber=' + str(item['partNumber']),
            callback=self.get_cross_info,
            meta={'item': item},
        )
```

Updated Pipeline:
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
import csv
import zeep
from XXX import settings

class XXXPipeline(object):
    # def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    #     self.settings = crawler.settings
    #     return cls()

    def spider_open(self, spider):
        self.data_file = open(settings.csv_file_path, 'a+')
        self.data_writer = csv.writer(self.data_file, delimiter=',')
        self.img_file = open(settings.img_csv_file_path, 'a+')
        self.img_writer = csv.writer(self.img_file, delimiter=',')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        data = make_request(item)
        if (data):
            mainCsv = self.data_writer
            imgPath = '/' + item['images'][0]['path']

            mainCsv.writerow([
                item['partNumber'], # sku,
                'simple', # _type
                'base', # _product_websites
                'Default', # _attribute_set
                4, # visiblity
                1, # status
                1, # is_in_stock
                10, # qty
                2, # tax_class_id
                1, # weight
                item['partNumber'] + data.PartDescription, # name
                9999, # price
                item['partNumber'] + ' ' + data.PartDescription, # description
                item['partNumber'] + ' ' + data.PartDescription, # short_description
                item['make'], # manufacturer_code
                imgPath, # image
                imgPath, # small_image
                imgPath, # thumbnail
                '"2,3"', # category_ids // Change based on site's categories
            ])

            imgCsv = self.img_writer

            iterimg = iter(item['images'])
            next(iterimg)
            for img in iterimg:
                imgCsv.writerow([
                    item['partNumber'],
                    '/' + img['path']
                ])

        return item

    def spider_close(self, spider):
        self.data_file.close()
        self.image_file.close()

def make_request(item):
    wsdl = 'https://XXX/b2b/parts_v2.asmx?WSDL'
    client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)
    # try:
    data = client.service.ExactPartLookup(
        userName='XXX',
        password='XXX',
        make=str(item['make']),
        partNumber=str(item['partNumber'])
    )

    return data.PartInformation_v2[0]
    # except:
    #     raise Exception('Couldn\'t get part information!')
```

Edit: I've found that my issue is actually due to this error: `maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object`

It seems that when the function `make_request` is called I'm getting this error. Not entirely sure what's causing this to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open files during initialization of your pipeline. Scrapy pipelines have handy method `spider_open()` which acts like **init** but only when spider starts - if in some cases it would, it won't do anything.

So you want to:

1. When spider opens - open up your files and create csv writer objects
2. When spider runs - write all items as rows
3. When spider closes - close up your files

Another important thing to note is that you should retrieve `settings` object from `crawler`, since scrapy can set settings at various places like via shell (like `scrapy crawl myspider -s CSV_FILE_LOCATION=/home/me/something.csv`).

All this put together should end up looking something along the lines of this:

```
class MyPipeline:

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler)
        # you want to get settings from crawler because settings.py is 
        # not the only place that can have some settings 
        self.settings = crawler.settings
        return cls()

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        # initiate file and writer objects once the spider opens
        self.data_file = open(self.settings.get('CSV_DATA'), 'a+')
        self.data_writer = csv.writer(self.data_file)
        self.image_file = open(settings.get('CSV_IMAGE'), 'a+')
        self.image_writer = csv.writer(self.image_file)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # write some rows!
        if 'image' in item:
            self.image_writer.write_row(item.values()
        else:
            self.data_writer.write_row(item.values())
        return item

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        # close the file objects
        self.data_file.close()
        self.image_file.close()
```

Comment: I have added in these changes to my project. However, it still isn't working. I have found out that It's actually another problem. Should I update my question for you? it seems that my `make_request` method is not returning anything. I'm getting an `maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object` error

Comment: @RyanScottCady Could you post full traceback of this error?

Comment: Well, I think I fixed this by using `str()` on the data inside of the request. Now I'm getting: `AttributeError: 'XXXPipeline' object has no attribute 'data_writer'`

Comment: @RyanScottCady oh sorry, it should be `open_spider` instead of `spider_open`, see my edit.